# Bootcamp Windows running on Parallels VS normal Parallels vm

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, virtualization, parallels-desktop

Since I have to use Windows for some Qt/C++. Last week I installed Windows on MBP 16" i9 16GB Bootcamp. I was using Windows on Parallels vm before and on Bootcamp it definitely runs faster. It seems memory on vm is stuck on 667MHz, I'm wondering why is that?

Then at some point I noticed Parallels can run Windows from bootcamp, memory is still on 667MHz. But I wondering about the performance expectations, should it be any faster than a normal vm?

Comment: Not answering the question which is a good question  but isn't the point of Qt that it will run cross platform

Comment: What does "memory on vm is stuck on 667MHz" mean?

Comment: @mmmmmm yes but sometimes an application is made of multiple components (not only Qt) and targets Windows only, in this case looks like best is to live in Windows for a while.

Comment: @nohillside it means if I go check memory clock on Windows running on Parallels vm it tells me memory clock is 667MHz even though MBP memory runs on 2667MHz.